# How to create a custom string using map value - Terraform

Tags: string, terraform

I struggle to create a custom string in Terraform when I loop through a list of `map` which contains a `map`.

The problem isn't the looping itself but creation of a custom string.

E.g

```
locals { 
       for var1 ... : [
          for var2 ... : {
            myString = "${var2.map["key1"]_${var2.map["key2"]}"  <-- This does NOT work as im using '"'
}]
            
}
```

Aware that the example does not work as I need to use double quote `"` to access the map value, but also because I need to use `"` for the creation of the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `}` and it should be `var`, not `var2`:

```
myString = "${var2.map["key1"]}_${var2.map["key2"]}"
```